# Trying separate the Oxygen Sensor electrical connector

Tags: o2-sensor, hybrid, lincoln

The rear O2 sensor needs replacing. I cannot figure out how to get the connector to separate.

2017 Lincoln MKZ Hybrid

I have tried pressing on the spot I think needs it. I have tried prying up on the tab that might release it. Still it refuses to release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tricks for disconnecting sensor connectors](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42439/tricks-for-disconnecting-sensor-connectors)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

1. Push the two halves of the sensor connector together.
2. Press the button on the sensor side.
3. While pressing the button, pull the connector apart.

It should really be that easy.

The green arrow is pointing to the back side of the latch which you need to press. This will lift the front side (red arrow) off of the nib which will allow the two parts to be pulled apart. By pushing the two halves together, you're taking off any straing which might be keeping the latch located onto the nib. If this doesn't work directly, you can try pushing a small/thin screwdriver over the top of the backside of the latch, then wiggling it under the front side.

[image]